# xamarin test recorder-Failure connecting to app

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests

I'm generated ipa file and trying to connect with iphone 5s device to record test but error is pop-up

```
Failure connecting to app
Unable to install app on device2016/05/27 10:22:09 [Preparing to install resigned-05-27-16-10-21-13-app.ipa to c32b1b2ce5bd5dcee551a17a37eb1880c46f61e2]
2016/05/27 10:22:12 [Installing resigned-05-27-16-10-21-13-app.ipa to c32b1b2ce5bd5dcee551a17a37eb1880c46f61e2]
2016/05/27 10:22:20 WARNING: could not locate Payload/infybr.app/SC_Info/infybr.sinf in archive!
Copying '/var/folders/5n/pnq040y167n973d9j0n35f140000gn/T/test-recorder/ios-injection/resigned-05-27-16-10-21-13-app.ipa' to device... DONE.
Installing 'in.fybr'
 - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%!!(MISSING))(MISSING)

 - ExtractingPackage (15%!!(MISSING))(MISSING)

 - InspectingPackage (20%!!(MISSING))(MISSING)

 - TakingInstallLock (20%!!(MISSING))(MISSING)

 - PreflightingApplication (30%!!(MISSING))(MISSING)

 - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%!!(MISSING))(MISSING)

 - VerifyingApplication (40%!!(MISSING))(MISSING)
 - Error occurred: ApplicationVerificationFailed
```

Comment: What version of Xamarin Test Recorder are you using?

Comment: Unable to start test run
The .ipa file does not seem to be linked with Calabash framework. can any one help me out.